# Struts 2.3: runtime add Interceptor

Tags: java, struts2, interceptor, struts2-interceptors, interceptorstack

I have a task to add/change interceptors runtime (with a plugin, do not have access to the parent configuration).

In previous version of Struts (2.0) that was pretty simple: classes ***InterceptorStackConfig*** and ***ActionConfig*** had methods ***addInterceptor*** and ***addInterceptors***.

In newer version (2.3) that methods moved into *Builder* static sub-class and I can't use them like before.

So that is a problem. Already spent several days trying to avoid it. Anyone can help?

My previous code example:

```
public class IpLoggingInterceptorConfiguration implements ConfigurationProvider {

private Interceptor interceptor;
private Configuration configuration;

@Override
public void init(Configuration configuration) throws ConfigurationException {
    this.configuration = configuration;
}

@Override
public void loadPackages() throws ConfigurationException {

    for (Object packageConfigName : configuration.getPackageConfigNames()) {
        try {
            String name = (String) packageConfigName;
            PackageConfig packageConfig = configuration.getPackageConfig(name);
            updatePackage(packageConfig);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

}

public void updatePackage(PackageConfig packageConfig) {
    Map interceptorConfigs = packageConfig.getInterceptorConfigs();

    for (Object stack : interceptorConfigs.keySet()) {

        if (!(interceptorConfigs.get(stack) instanceof InterceptorStackConfig)) continue;

        InterceptorStackConfig interceptorStackConfig = (InterceptorStackConfig) interceptorConfigs.get(stack);

        InterceptorMapping interceptorMapping = new InterceptorMapping("iplogging", getInterceptor());

        List<InterceptorMapping> list = new ArrayList<InterceptorMapping>();
        list.addAll(interceptorStackConfig.getInterceptors());
        interceptorStackConfig.getInterceptors().clear();
        interceptorStackConfig.addInterceptor(interceptorMapping);
        interceptorStackConfig.addInterceptors(list);
    }

    for (String key : packageConfig.getActionConfigs().keySet()) {
        ActionConfig actionConfig = packageConfig.getActionConfigs().get(key);

        InterceptorMapping interceptorMapping = new InterceptorMapping("iplogging", getInterceptor());

        List<InterceptorMapping> list = new ArrayList<InterceptorMapping>();
        list.addAll(actionConfig.getInterceptors());
        actionConfig.getInterceptors().clear();
        actionConfig.addInterceptor(interceptorMapping);
        actionConfig.addInterceptors(list);
    }
}


@Override
public void destroy() {
}

@Override
public boolean needsReload() {
    return false;
}

@Override
public void register(ContainerBuilder arg0, LocatableProperties arg1)
        throws ConfigurationException {
}

public Interceptor getInterceptor() {
    return interceptor;
}

public void setInterceptor(Interceptor interceptor) {
    this.interceptor = interceptor;
}
}
```

Comment: Because now interceptorStackConfig.getInterceptors() - is UnmodifiableCollection :(

Comment: What is a minor version?

Comment: I think that modification was since new versions line for xwork:
http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.struts.xwork/xwork-core

Comment: How do you run your project if you don't have access to the parent configuration?

Comment: I was faced with a similar issue... and didn't come to an acceptable solution. I think you may be able to rebuild the entire configuration, but that seemed like a pain. The easiest way would be to create a new interceptor which allows you to dynamically add further interceptors (a ChainOfResponsibility Interceptor you can add to this interceptors stack dynamically).

Comment: Didn't think to much about what you're actually trying to do, you know you could look into Spring AOP. If you want application level logging, that is pretty much the definition of a cross-cutting-concern and so it is the canonical example used for AOP.

Answer (score 0):

I found and know, this solution is ugly, but simple and works... Maybe someone have better.

```
try {
            Field interceptorsListField=InterceptorStackConfig.class.getDeclaredField("interceptors");
            interceptorsListField.setAccessible(true);
            List<InterceptorMapping> interceptorsList= (List<InterceptorMapping>) interceptorsListField.get(interceptorStackConfig);

            List<InterceptorMapping> list = new ArrayList<>();
            list.add(interceptorMapping);
            list.addAll(interceptorStackConfig.getInterceptors());
            interceptorsListField.set(interceptorStackConfig,list);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```